React Hook Form + Zod: useForm formState returning proper isValid value, but errors is empty
I am using useForm react hook + zod for validation schemas.
From the formState all values returned are as expected, but the "errors" object. I am trying to set hasError of an input and no matter the value "errors" is always empty.
  // Initialize react-hook-form with default values
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    reset,
    getValues,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, touchedFields, isValid, isDirty },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: initialValues,
    resolver: zodResolver(OpeningHoursBodySchema),
  });

<Box mr={3.75} width="auto">
  <InputField
    border
    hasError={touchedFields.address?.street && !!errors.address?.street}
    label={
      <Typography display="block" variant="mainBold">
        {ts("general.street")}
        <Typography color="red.main" component="sup">
          *
        </Typography>
      </Typography>
    }
    {...register("address.street")}
    smallSize
    placeholder={ts("general.street")}
  />
</Box>;

Those are the schemas that I use:
export const ModuleAddressSchema = z.object({
  street: z.string().min(1, { message: REQUIRED }),
  houseNumber: z.string().min(1, { message: REQUIRED }),
  city: z.string().min(1, { message: REQUIRED }),
  zip: z.string().min(1, { message: REQUIRED }),
});

export const OpeningHoursSchema = z.object({
  eventId: z.number(),
  startDate: z.string().min(1, { message: "Date should not be empty" }),
  endDate: z.string().min(1, { message: "Date should not be empty" }),
  timezone: z.string().optional(),
  weeklyOpeningTimes: WeeklyOpeningTimesSchema,
  address: ModuleAddressSchema.refine(
    (moduleAddress) => {
      return Object.values(moduleAddress).every((field) => field.length > 0);
    },
    { message: "This field is required" }
  ),
});

I added the .refine(), because the trying with .min() didn't work and I thought the issue may be the nested object schema.
Also used this from the useForm documentation to debug my resolver and it's showing the proper errors with messages from the zod .refine() method
resolver: async (data, context, options) => {
  console.log(
    "validation result",
    await zodResolver(OpeningHoursBodySchema)(data, context, options)
  )
  return zodResolver(OpeningHoursBodySchema)(data, context, options)
}


Is it not working only for this specific field?

It's not working for any of the address  fields. This makes me think the issue is because the address is an nested object and it has some sort of different behavior. I also added mode: "onChange" to set the validation trigger mode of the forms and the startDate and endDate errors are shown properly in errors object when value doesn't match the validation.

I understand, Please try to make a Minimal, Reproducible Example so it will be easier to help you.
